# How can I fix the following jQuery Validate issue in Umbraco?

Tags: javascript, jquery, umbraco

I am using the Umbraco CMS to load a jQuery file that uses the jQuery Validate plugin. The code seems to work fine on my local machine but not in Umbraco. The form is not being validated, jQuery itself is loaded and working fine as I have tested this with a window.alert(); call. Although, saying this an if statement is not working in the CMS but is working on my local machine.

So this works fine on my local machine, but doesn't in Umbraco:

```
var wheelchairOptions = $("#wheelchair-options");
wheelchairOptions.hide();

$('#00N25000002TSTd').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") === true){
                wheelchairOptions.show();
        alert("working");
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") === false){
                wheelchairOptions.hide();
            }
        });
```

Due to how Umbraco loads in code, it's not a simple copy and paste. This is how the code is laid out in Umbraco:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"  async defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

      var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        //alert(response);
//$('#re_button').show();
$('#re_button').prop("disabled", false);
      };
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('example3', {
          'sitekey' : '6LdmNKkUAAAAANgIH_Z_IJCstpLT4BaLqc76CTKn',
          'callback' : verifyCallback,
          'theme' : 'light'
        });
      };

        $("#nx-form").validate({
          rules: {
            name: {
              required: true,
              lettersonly: true,
              minlength: 2,
              maxlength: 80,
              normalizer: function( value ) {
                return $.trim( value );
              }
            },
            email: {
              required: true,
              email: true,
              minlength: 2,
              maxlength: 80
            },
            phone: {
              required: true,
              phoneUK: true,
              minlength: 2,
              maxlength: 40
            },
            subject: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 2,
              maxlength: 40
            },
            "00N25000002TSEr": {
              required: true,
              minlength: 2,
              maxlength: 255
            },
            "00N25000002TSFu": {
              required: true,
              lettersonly: true,
              minlength: 2,
              maxlength: 255
            },
            "00N25000002TSGJ": {
              required: true,
              lettersonly: true,
              minlength: 2,
              maxlength: 255
            },
            "00N25000002TSJ3": {
              required: true,
              time: true
            },
            "00N25000002TSJD": {
              required: true,
              dateISO: true
            },
            "00N25000002TSTd": {
              required: true
            }

          }
        });


    // Tests to see if name field contains letters only
    $.validator.addMethod( "lettersonly", function( value, element ) {
        return this.optional( element ) || /^[a-z\s ,.'-]+$/i.test( value ); }, "Letters only please" );


    // Tests to see if tel field contains numbers only
    $.validator.addMethod( "phoneUK", function( phone_number, element ) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace( /\(|\)|\s+|-/g, "" );
    return this.optional( element ) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match( /^(?:(?:(?:00\s?|\+)44\s?)|(?:\(?0))(?:\d{2}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?\s?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}\s?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?\s?\d{4,5})$/ );
}, "Please specify a valid phone number" );


    // Tests to see if departure fields contain correct time format
$.validator.addMethod( "time", function( value, element ) {
    return this.optional( element ) || /^([01]\d|2[0-3]|[0-9])(:[0-5]\d){1,2}$/.test( value );
}, "Please enter a valid time in the format HH:MM, between 00:00 and 23:59. For e.g. 16:30" );


var wheelchairOptions = $("#wheelchair-options");
wheelchairOptions.hide();

$('#00N25000002TSTd').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") === true){
                wheelchairOptions.show();
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") === false){
                wheelchairOptions.hide();
            }
        });

    </script>


</head>

<body>

<form action="https://national-express--bgdev.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" id="nx-form" name="nx-form"  class="nx-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="orgid" value="00D2500000090xE" />

  <input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="http://www.google.com" />

  <input type="hidden" id="recordType" name="recordType" value="01225000000En7U" />


  <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  --> 
  <!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    --> 
  <!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          --> 
  <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              --> 
  <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  --> 
  <!--  value="mikebackhouse@brightgen.com">                                    --> 
  <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 0.85em">* Required field</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="name">Contact Name</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input class="form-control nx-form-control" id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="email">Email</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input class="form-control nx-form-control" id="email" name="email" type="email" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="phone">Phone</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input class="form-control nx-form-control" id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" /></div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="subject">Subject</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input  id="subject" class="form-control nx-form-control" maxlength="80" name="subject" size="20" type="text" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSEr">Ticket Number:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input  id="00N25000002TSEr" class="form-control nx-form-control" maxlength="255" name="00N25000002TSEr" size="20" type="text" /></div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSFu">Travelling From:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input  id="00N25000002TSFu" class="form-control nx-form-control" maxlength="255" name="00N25000002TSFu" size="20" type="text" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSGJ">Travelling To:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input  id="00N25000002TSGJ" class="form-control nx-form-control" maxlength="255" name="00N25000002TSGJ" size="20" type="text" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSJ3">Departure Time:</label><span class="timeContainer"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input id="00N25000002TSJ3" class="form-control nx-form-control" name="00N25000002TSJ3" placeholder="HH:MM" size="12" type="text" /></div>
             </span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSJD">Date of Travel:</label><span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input id="00N25000002TSJD" class="form-control nx-form-control" name="00N25000002TSJD" size="12" type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YY" /></div>
             </span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSTd">Travel with Wheelchair?:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input  id="00N25000002TSTd" name="00N25000002TSTd" type="checkbox" value="1" /></div>
             </span>
        </div>

        <div id="wheelchair-options">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSTx">Wheelchair Make</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input class="form-control nx-form-control"  id="00N25000002TSTx" maxlength="255" name="00N25000002TSTx" size="20" type="text"/></div>
             </span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSU7">Wheelchair Model</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input class="form-control nx-form-control"  id="00N25000002TSU7" maxlength="255" name="00N25000002TSU7" size="20" type="text"/></div>
             </span>
        </div>      
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSUM">Age of Child 1:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control nx-form-control nx-form-dropdown" id="00N25000002TSUM" name="00N25000002TSUM" title="Age of Child 1">
                <option value="">--None--</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSUR">Age of Child 2:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control nx-form-control nx-form-dropdown" id="00N25000002TSUR" name="00N25000002TSUR" title="Age of Child 2">
                <option value="">--None--</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSUW">Age of Child 3:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control nx-form-control nx-form-dropdown" id="00N25000002TSUW" name="00N25000002TSUW" title="Age of Child 3">
                <option value="">--None--</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSUb">Age of Child 4:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control nx-form-control nx-form-dropdown" id="00N25000002TSUb" name="00N25000002TSUb" title="Age of Child 4">
                <option value="">--None--</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TSUg">Age of Child 5:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control nx-form-control nx-form-dropdown" id="00N25000002TSUg" name="00N25000002TSUg" title="Age of Child 5">
                <option value="">--None--</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label for="00N25000002TTcp">Customer Entered Summary:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><textarea class="form-control nx-form-control text_area" id="00N25000002TTcp" name="00N25000002TTcp" rows="3" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea></div>
        </div>

<div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
        <!--<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdmNKkUAAAAANgIH_Z_IJCstpLT4BaLqc76CTKn"></div>-->
<div id="example3"></div>
    </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 form_spacing">
            <button id="re_button"  class="primaryButton primaryButton--blue button_custom" type="submit" disabled="disabled" >Submit Query</button>
        </div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I think the issue may be related to HOW jQuery Validate is being loaded in, I have tried moving the jQuery tags to just before the  tag but to no avail.

What should happen is on change and then blur the forms input fields should be tested for validation, with an error message underneath the relevant input field.

Comment: If this jQuery Validate code works on your local machine then obviously you don't have a jQuery Validate issue.  Have you done any logical and methodical troubleshooting?  Have you checked the console for errors?  View the browser DOM from your local machine where it's working to the browser DOM where it's not working and compare it line by line.

Comment: Your code as you've posted it above is working perfectly fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/g7sfvwty/  ~ there is not much we can do for you when you post code that works already.